# sql complex join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the three related tables that i would like to retrieve data from using joins: tbl_accounts containing the account details of users, tbl_users containing the personal details of users and tbl_t_records that contains the transaction details of all users.

In the **tbl_accounts** i have a foreign key column ***holder*** that helps link it to the **tbl_users** and in the **tbl_t_records** I have the foreign key columns ***oaccount*** and ***daccount*** each linking to **tbl_accounts** but the **oaccount** stores the details for the account from which the transaction originated while **daccount** stores the details for the account to which the transaction is destined

here is the snippet fro the tbl_accounts table
[image: tbl_accounts screenshot]

Here is the one for tbl_users
[image]

This is the one for tbl_t_records
[image]

I would like to create a query that return the name of a sender, receiver and the transaction id using joins.
so far this is what I have tried

```
    SELECT tbl_t_records.id transaction_id,
            CONCAT(tbl_users.lname,tbl_users.othername)as sender, 
            amount,
            CONCAT(tbl_users.lname,tbl_users.othername)as receiver 
    FROM tbl_t_records
        INNER JOIN tbl_accounts on oaccount = tbl_accounts.id 
        INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_accounts.holder = tbl_users.id
```

this does not give me the details of the destination account rather it only presents the data fro the sender that it uses as the same for the reciever as shown here
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join several times, as follows:

```
select 
    r.id transaction_id,
    concat(u1.lname, u1.othername) sender, 
    concat(u2.lname, u2.othername) receiver, 
    r.amount
from tbl_t_records r
inner join tbl_accounts a1 on a1.id = r.oaccount
inner join tbl_users u1 on u1.id = a1.holder
inner join tbl_accounts a2 on a2.id = r.daccount
inner join tbl_users u2 on u2.id = a2.holder
```

This query starts from the transaction table and then follows the relationships related to `oaccount` through `tbl_accounts` (aliased `a1`) to `tbl_users` (aliased `u1`). Another series of joins starts from `daccount` and brings the related user data (aliases `a2/u2`).

Answer (score 1):

You just need multiple `join`s -- a separate set for each name:

```
SELECT r.*,
       CONCAT(uo.lname, uo.othername) as sender,
       CONCAT(ud.lname, ud.othername) as receiver
FROM tbl_t_records r JOIN
     tbl_accounts ao
     ON r.oaccount = ao.id JOIN
     tbl_users uo
     ON ao.holder = uo.id JOIN
     tbl_accounts ad
     ON r.daccount = ad.id JOIN
     tbl_users ud
     ON ad.holder = ud.id;
```